# Increase hardware RAID1 volume size

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, ibm, lsi

We are working with an IBM server and a SAS1064ET hardware RAID controller. We used two 73.4 GB 10k SAS HDDs with RAID1. As we wanted to upgrade the storage, we replaced one after another with a 600GB HDD and always waited until the RAID1 has been synchronized. Now, the question is, how can we increase the volume size to use the entire disk space? We found the following utilities:

- CFGGEN from IBM
- lsiutil from LSI

With neither of them we were able to change to volume size. We are running Ubuntu 16.04 using a logical volume. What are possible solutions to increase the volume size? Did we miss something in the utilities? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed it by deleting the RAID volume in the RAID BIOS and directly creating a new one without initializing it. Then we could increase the size of the LVM volume in Ubuntu.